# Member value of mixin trait missing a concrete super implementation

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Given code snippet:

```scala
abstract class A {
  protected val x: Int
}
trait B extends A {
  println(x)
}
case class C(override protected val x: Int) extends A with B
```

I encountered the following problems:

1. The code compiles if I'm pasting the whole snippet into the scala REPL using `:paste` mode; however it *doesn't* if I paste each class block one by one (i.e., firstly paste `A` definition, then `B`, then `C`). What's happening here?
2. When it doesn't compile, the compiler emits the error:

   ```
   scala> case class C(override protected val x: Int) extends A with B
   <console>:13: error: Member value x of mixin trait iw$B is missing a concrete super implementation.
          case class C(override protected val x: Int) extends A with B
                     ^
   ```

   I don't understand what it means exactly. Why `x` in `B` misses a concrete implementation? Didn't `C` provided it?

I've tested both on Scala 2.12.11 and 2.13.3, on macOS 10.15.7

*Edit*: Here's a gif for what I mean for pasting one by one. And the error is only triggered if you paste *one-by-one*.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure where you are getting this error from, but it compiles both in Scala [2.12](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/EjCLYyDJR3SBKPt9hmYjLg/2) and in Scala [2.13](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/EjCLYyDJR3SBKPt9hmYjLg/1)

Comment: @TomerShetah Hi, I've made a gif. Hope it'll clarify what I mean.

Comment: Each line of REPL input (at each prompt) is its own compilation unit. That's why you can redefine the same `val` multiple times. Something not possible in real code. These individual compilation units usually interact with each other smoothly, but sometimes there are rough edges.

Comment: @jwvh So why the code won't compile when each class/trait is placed in separate compilation unit? Actually this is what happens in my real project. I have `A`, `B`, `C`-like classes in different files, and the `sbt compile` reports the same error. This is why I tried simplifying the case into the code snippet and finally discovered more problems in REPL.

Comment: That will have to be answered by someone with more in-depth knowledge of the compiler (and compilation units) than I have.

Comment: @TomerShetah I managed to reproduce https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/f1432fd919efd975a1151c545d71af33 Scala 2.13.3, 2.13.4.

Comment: @Naitree Looks like a bug. Bugs should be reported here: https://github.com/scala/bug

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/xeZwDLbVQvq2qZqjIgFo7w/1

Comment: @DmytroMitin Thanks for the gist. I've reported the issue, see https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12249

Comment: @Naitree Great! Thanks.

Comment: That's a good one. Re: "Something not possible in real code." Let's stipulate that Scala code transformed to run as a "script" or in "REPL" is real code, as it goes to the heart of Scala as "scalable". The other oddity of REPL is that it is a resident compiler, which enables another class of bugs.